# onclick Button, start playing a sound

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a beginner and have developed a simple app which plays a sound when you click some button. The app runs just fine, but when i click it, there´s no sound.

Olá! Fiz um app que simplesmente reproduz um som ao clicar em um botão.
O app emula normalmente (abre no emulador), mas quando clico no botão para reproduzir um som, ele não funciona.

MainActivity.java

```
package mucap.esy.es.preplay;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
public class BasicScreenActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.justdoit);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
 }
}
```

I have everything set (file, button) but it won´t work with this code.
I found nothing in `logcat`, can someone help me?

Comment: Have you checked volume of device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please Update your MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.justdoit);
    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: and how would i add new buttons and new sounds? like adding a new button to play another sound?

Comment: if this doesn't help please start a new question and leave a link here